# Python Pyomo gets error: Constant objective detected, replacing with a placeholder to prevent solver failure

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

**I am trying to solve a mathematical programming problem with Pyomo**

Here is my code:

```
model = AbstractModel()

*####communities*

model.I = set()

*####suppliers*

model.J = set()

model.c = Param(model.J)  

model.p = Param(model.I)  

model.s = Param(model.J)  

model.e = Param(model.J)  

model.b = Param(model.I)
```

**Decision variables totally there are 19*6 = 114**

```
model.q = Var(model.I,model.J,domain = NonNegativeReals) #bought quantity
```

**definition of the objective function**

```
def obj_expression(model): 
    return sum(model.c[j]*sum(model.q[i,j] for i in model.I) for j in model.J)  
 
      
model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)

####q11+q12+q13...q1j >= pi

def cons_1(model, i): 
     return sum(model.q[i,j] for j in model.J) >= model.p[i]
model.vaccine_quantity = Constraint(model.I, rule = cons_1)
```

**total quantity of vaccine j smaller than the supply j**

```
def cons_2(model,j):
    return sum(model.q[i,j] for i in model.I) <= model.s[j]
model.supply = Constraint(model.J, rule = cons_2)
```

**budget**

```
def cons_3(model, i):
    return sum(model.q[i,j] for j in model.J) <= model.b[i]
```

**My data:**

```
param J : c        s      e :=

"China 1" 10      1000   0.6

"Russian" 10      700    0.92

"UK"      3       2000   0.76

;
```

```
param I :                    p         b   :=  
"Andalucia"                  845      40000

"Aragón"                     132      35000

"Principado de Asturias"     275      10000

"Comunitat Valenciana"       500      40000
;
```

**I have reviewed several times, but I don't know where is the problem.
The warning is:**

```
WARNING: Constant objective detected, replacing with a placeholder to prevent
    solver failure.
WARNING: Empty constraint block written in LP format - solver may error
[    0.05] Processing results
    Number of solutions: 1
    Solution Information
      Gap: 0.0
      Status: feasible
      Function Value: 0.0
]
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: There are no errors! Those are just warnings. As you can see from the output there's a solution. I suspect that those warnings are related to the way you are creating the model instance (and passing the data files to it), unfortunatelly you omitted the code where you are doing that.